# Page Methods throwing Undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use page methods to call a function and I am getting a "PageMethods is undefinded" error. I have used them before whilst using C# but not VB so I'm wondering if my syntax is wrong as all examples I can find are C#.
I am also wondering if it's because my scriptmanager is on the master page?

I've read about this error everywhere but everything I have appears to be correct!

Can anyone point me at what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

My code:

**Part of Master Page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"  EnablePageMethods="true" >
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="header">~~~~~
```

**Content Page HTML**

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function selectZones(commaSeparatedList){
            PageMethods.Zones(commaSeparatedList);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="navigationPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">

<a href='' onclick='selectZones("blah,blah,blah"); return false;'>click here</a>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="functionsMenuPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Content Page Code Behind**

```
    Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class TestClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    <WebMethod()>
    Protected Shared Sub Zones(ByVal zones As String)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("test = " & zones)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try placing the ScriptManager in the .aspx of the content page. Any luck?

Comment: Hmm.. next step of debugging: create brand new .aspx page (without master page) and place ScriptManager and PageMethod in there. Does it work? As you see, I'm trying to verify the problem is with the ScriptManager being in master page.

Comment: By the way, when you post comment alert the person by putting @username for example @Shadow will be enough otherwise unless the person has the question in the favorites, he/she won't get any notification.

Comment: @Shadow I worked it out. It appeared my method needed to be public rather than protected. I was barking but the wrong tree

Comment: @Bex thanks for sharing.... still find it weird that the whole PageMethods was undefined.. more likely behavior is to get undefined only for the specific page method that is not public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out. Nothing to do with the script manager or anything like that.

My method in the code behind needed to be **public** so now reads as follows:

```
 <WebMethod()> 
Public Shared Sub Zones(ByVal zones As String) 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("test = " & zones) 
End Sub
```

Did not realise this was needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have issue where the "selectZones" method is running before the scripts from script manager are completing to run.   I suggest you try to put call into document ready or event and see if call works at this time.   Scripts will run when they are seen by client browser, and if downloaded like script manager other scripts later in page will run first.

Comment: How would I do this? Could you give an example?