# PageMethods what is issue with it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm getting "Object Error" on line

```
function readWURecord()
{
var ifUSD = "";
try
{var mtcnNo=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtReferenceNo').value;
if(mtcnNo=='')
{
alert('Provide Reference Number');return false;}
var adoConn=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var filename;
var filenamecsv1;
fs=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
filename=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdPath').value+'Trans.mdb';
filenamecsv1="D://Data.csv";
if(fs.FileExists(filename)==true)
{
adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+filename+";Persist                                         Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=tradb897");
}
else if(fs1.FileExists(filenamecsv1)==true)
{
PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=TxtReferenceNo.ClientID%>").value);
```

and

```
function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName)
{
alert("response");
}
```

Can anybody help me what issues are with **PageMethods.GetCurrentTime** method?

Comment: whereabouts is your JavaScript held? Is it in the .aspx page itself or is it in a separate script?

Comment: We need the javascript - not your server side code

Comment: PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=TxtReferenceNo.ClientID%>").value,     OnSuccess); is java script code and the function function OnSuccess is also javascript code iprovide sever side code to understand my problem dear

Comment: dear all of my code is in .js file what should i do?  its my task to do in javascript

Comment: name error is "type Error" and Description is "Object Error" reference number is numeric value and in .aspx i am using string

Comment: We need your javascript that's in the .js file

Comment: Please post your code as edits to your original post! :)

Comment: I think it is unlikely that your `<%=` inline tag will be correctly rendered on the client/browser (ie with the serverside evaluation of `TxtReferenceNo.ClientID`). If you include the script actually in your `<head>` of the .aspx file you may have more luck...

Comment: I say close, we can't help the OP if they won't let us

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page Methods throwing Undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325176/page-methods-throwing-undefined)

Comment: See in the duplicate question.. you have to make `GetCurrentTime` in your C# code behind *public*. By the way use `@` to notify people when you post reply to their comments. For example `@ElRonnoco` would notify him you posted new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do add some whitspace (indentation) in your code. Secondly "<%=TxtReferenceNo.ClientID%>" will not get resolved if you do not generate a file. And if you have ".js" file then it is static (unless you somehow set it up not to be static).

So you should either set some variable outside of JS (e.g. in your ASP file) and use it in your function or call readWURecord with ClientID parameter or something. Or even better - don't do it in JScript - ActiveX only works in Internet Explorer.